# How can I correctly attach record object to data context in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to switch data context for some records. So basically I have db context A and B, I fetch records using A, then I switch to B, alter records, and save them.

When I call Attach for B, I get exception that records are using by multiple data context, when I add Detach for A, I get exception, that records are not attached to A.

So how can I switch the data context?

### Example

**db_creator** is creator of db context. Here I fetch the data (corrected version):

```
using (var db = db_creator.Create())
{
  var coll = db.Mailing.Where(it => !it.mail_IsSent).ToList(); // (*)
  coll.ForEach(it => db.Detach(it));
  return coll;
}
```

(*) the mistake was caused by refactoring this piece, I created extra data context, and then later I tried to detach records from another one.

Now I would like to switch data context to new one, do some computation and modifications and save the records. **coll** is **List** of the records:

```
using (var db = db_creator.Create())
{
  coll.ForEach(it => db.Mailing.Attach(it));
  ...
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: why are you using 2 contexts for reads and writes?

Comment: Show some code affected by the error.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, done, see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend change your design and have ONE context at a time. (Based on your project type this could vary. Usually in web apps it's one context per http request.)

For example in a web application, you can do this like below:

```
protected MyContext Context
{
    get
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current.Items["MyContext"];
        if (context == null)
        {
            context = new MyContext();
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("MyContext", context);
        }
        return context as MyContext;
    }
}
```

And dispose it in your Application_EndRequest:

```
app.EndRequest += (sender, args) =>
{
    HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove("MyContext");
}
```

If you have multiple project types, then consider using an Ioc.
But if you still want to use two contexts, you can do as below(`myEntity` is your object you want to detach/attach):

```
if (context1.Entry(myEntity).State != EntityState.Detached);
{
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)context1).ObjectContext.Detach(myEntity);
}
context2.MyEntities.Attach(myEntity);
```

Comment: First part -- "have ONE context at a time", this is exactly what I am doing, and this leads to using multiple data context, IOW: data context should be used for single tasks, it shouldn't live too long. Second part -- does it work for you? Because I already tried detaching records, and I got exception as well (I wrote about it in my post above).

Comment: When you use dbCreator.Create() you get a new context. Hence, you do not have access to the old context. I'd do something like `var ctx = dbCreator.Create()` and in the end of the method, before return (and lose the current context in use), I'd detach the entities from context. It'd be a lot clearer if you include the part that you get exception when detaching entities.

Comment: Oh boy, when refactoring this part, I made stupid mistake of actually creating 2 data contexts, so I tried to detach records from data context which didn't contain them. Thank you for that comment.

Comment: I should add that you need to set the entity state to modified after performing attach if you plan to update it. Otherwise it is "Unchanged" and SaveChanges will not perform an update: `context2.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myEntity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);`

Comment: @DonAndre: In Entity Framework 4.1, You can change the state easier by using: `myContext.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Answer (score 1):

I have come to the conclusion that it's best (i.e. easier to avoid problems) to use `ApplyCurrentValues` instead of attaching. That is because when you call `Attach` there are several things going on that we don't know about, but which may surface in one way or the other through an exception. I prefer to do things the way I have control over what is done.

```
var myMailings = db_creator.Create().Mailing.Where(it => !it.mail_IsSent).ToList();
... // make modifications and retrieve coll a collection of Mailing objects
using (var db = db_creator.Create()) {
  ... // if you want to further modify the objects in coll you should do this before writing it to the context
  foreach (Mailing it in coll) {
    if (it.EntityKey != null) db.GetObjectByKey(it.EntityKey); // load entity
    else db.Mailing.Single(x => x.YourId == it.YourId); // load the entity when EntityKey is not available, e.g. because it's a POCO
    db.Mailing.ApplyCurrentValues(it); // sets the entity state to Modified
  }
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

EDIT:

I tested the performance of this vs using Attach. It should be noted that for a simple table with an integer primary key, an int, a float and a string column for updating 1000 entries: the difference was 2.6s vs 0.27s, so this is significantly slower.

EDIT2:

A similar question was raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544849/entity-framework-4-applycurrentvaluestentity-vs-objectstatemanager-changeobj). There the answer warned about using ApplyCurrentValues in conjunction with timestamp columns.

I also compared performance when loading the entity with `db.GetObjectByKey(it.EntityKey)` and there the performance difference is much smaller. ApplyCurrentValues then just takes 0.44s.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is no-go for sure -- performance, you are hitting database twice, and since you explicitly fetching the data, there is nothing that can be done on EF part. However, using Attach is "cheaper" because you don't use db at this point.

Comment: Yes this is significantly more expensive. I put together a quick test and edited the answer.