# Entity Framework CreateObjectset Attach method not updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am using an example off [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94782/Revisiting-the-Repository-and-Unit-of-Work-Pattern/?fid=1579705&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick) to update database tables in SQL Server 2008 following the repository and Unit of Work pattern.

While I have got the Insert working. I am having a hard time getting the update and delete working. The update gives no error, and does not update. The delete gives an InvalidOperationException like this `The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.`

For insert and delete I am using the IObjectSet methods as given in the example. For Update I am using the IObjectSet.Attach(entity) method to which I send the modified object.

Code for Repository and Unit of work classes below:

**Repository Class**

> namespace DataAccess  {
>
> ```
> public interface IGenericRepository<T>
>     where T : class
> {
>     void AddRow(T entity);
>     void UpdateRow(T entity);
>     void Delete(T entity);
> }
>
>
> public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
>         where T : class
> {
>
>
>     protected IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;
>
>     public GenericRepository(ObjectContext Context)
>     {
>         _objectSet = Context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
>
>     }
>
>
>
>
>         public void AddRow(T entity)
>         {
>             _objectSet.AddObject(entity);
>         }
>
>         public void UpdateRow(T entity)
>         {
>             _objectSet.Attach(entity);
>         }
>
>         public void Delete(T entity)
>         {
>             _objectSet.DeleteObject(entity);
>         }
>
>    }
> }
> ```

**Unit Of Work Class**

```
namespace DataAccess 
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        IGenericRepository<User> Users { get; }
        void Commit();
    }


    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {

        private readonly ObjectContext _context;
        private UserRepository _userRepository;

        public UnitOfWork(ObjectContext Context)
        {

            if (Context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Context wasn't supplied");
            }
            _context = Context;
        }



        public void Commit()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

            public IGenericRepository<User> Users
            {
                get 
                {
                    if (_userRepository == null)
                    {
                        _userRepository = new UserRepository(_context);
                    }

                    return _userRepository;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**Finally this is how I use it for update in my calling code**

```
public void UpdateUser(UserData userData)
{
   using (mEntities context = new mEntities())
   {
     UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(context);
     User usr = new User(); //This is the Entity Framework class
     usr.ID = userData.RowID;
     usr.UserName = userData.Username;   //usr.UserName is the primary key in the table

     uow.Users.UpdateRow(usr);
     uow.Commit();
   }
}
```

But the update doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong here? I am using VS2010 with EF 4

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way that worked was to change the update method in the Generic repository class

```
public void UpdateRow(T entity)
{
    _objectSet.Attach(entity);
    _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The UnitOfWork class doesn't need the Commit() method anymore. so now my calling code does just this..

```
public void UpdateUser(UserData userData)
{
   using (mEntities context = new mEntities())
   {
     UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(context);
     User usr = new User(); //This is the Entity Framework class
     usr.ID = userData.RowID;
     usr.UserName = userData.Username;   //usr.UserName is the primary key in the table

     uow.Users.UpdateRow(usr);
     //uow.Commit();
   }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else. Although I havnt tested this thoroughly I think this should work for most situations.

Answer (score 1):

After you attached an item in `UpdateRow` you need to mark it as modified. Entities are attached in the state Unchanged. However to modify the state you'll need access to the `ObjectStateManager` which is a property of the context. In EF 4.1 [I was told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658069/how-can-i-correctly-attach-record-object-to-data-context-in-entity-framework/7658478#comment9309412_7658478) there's a method `Entry()` in the context that allows you to set the state as well.

To delete an entity it has to be present in the context. If it hasn't been loaded you'll have to attach it before deleting it.

Also be aware about the [difference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/28/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-2-complex-types-deferred-loading-and-explicit-loading.aspx) between using `new()` and `CreateObject<T>()`.

Comment: changed my repository delete method to now read as ... 

    _objectSet.Attach(entity);
    _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
    _objectSet.DeleteObject(entity);

Comment: And the error message is the same and where was it thrown? When you can set the object's state, I assume it would also find the object later. Does update work at least?

Comment: I got it to work by making some minor modifications to the unit of work class and the repository class and also the way I was using it in my calling code.. was too late to verify it thoroughly .. will check it when I am home and report back. Thanks for the hint. It opened new ways to approach this issue..

Comment: Good to hear, I'd be interested if you post your solution. The thing about EF that irritates me most is how code that feels like it should work often does not.

Comment: Sure,I'll post it provided it passes my testing :) .. I agree on the EF irritation bit. Developers shouldn't have to tell EF if the ObjectState has changed. It should be smart enough to know that already. I'm considering NHibernate or BLToolkit next. Have you any experience in those ORMs?

Comment: I'm coming from Linq2Sql and there was an additional boolean paramter in Attach() that said it should treat it as modified. Great! That's valuable information for developers. Later I did switch to EF because I wanted support for TPH inheritance and the whole POCO support sounded nice as well. Although, in retrorespect, I shunned to really make use of POCOs and instead implemented a nice mapping solution. Btw, look [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/11/27/attaching-modified-entities-in-ef-4.aspx), there's a nice AttachAsModified extension method.