# Cloning the changes of an EF ObjectContext to another new context to save changes async safely

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I am using EF 4.0 without code first, I need to make the save operation async, the problem is that the ObjectContext is not thread-safe, and my context has many objects bound to the WPF UI, I am thinking of cloning the changes of my entities into another context and save that context safely in another thread,

Is there any easy way to clone the changes?? I know that the keyword is ObjectStateManager, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure this is impossible. The `ObjectStateManager` is the heart and soul of tracking and storing changes for the `ObjectContext` and is closely entwined with the context. It would require mere surgery to transplant one. More technically speaking, you would not be able clone one without applying tons of reflection, because most of its state is managed internally. And then, `ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager` doesn't have a setter.

The root of your problem is to have a context per view (at least, maybe even one global context?). Context per view is a viable option for rich client applications, but requiring asynchronous processing changes the parameters. A long context lifetime is no longer an option.

A solution could be to bind (disconnected) view models to the UI, in stead of entity objects, and instantiate a context in a separate thread (well, `Task`) to save changes.

Another new feature in EF 6 (now in alpha) may be interesting to you: [built-in async](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/28/async-in-entity-framework-6-0.aspx). I never experimented with it yet, but it looks promising.